# I want to determine if the numbers in an array are factors of 50

Tags: delphi

I want to see if the numbers in an array are factors of 50 or not

I created an array of integers and tried to determine using mod , but can't seem to get it right

```
//Global
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Num: array [1 .. 100] of integer;
  ask: integer;
  i, j, temp: integer;

procedure TForm1.btnDisplayCriteriaClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  temp, fac :integer;
begin
  fac:=num[ask];

  if rbgCriteria.ItemIndex=0 then
  begin
    for I := 1 to ask do
    begin

      if fac mod 50=0 then
      fac:=num[i];
      Inc(fac);
    end;
    redDisplay.Lines.Add(IntToStr(fac)+' is a factor of 50')
  end;
end;
```

I expect it to show whether number() is a factor of 50 but instead I get the position

Comment: Ask your self what fac is when you apply mod 50. If you took some time to debug your program you'd see the problem.  This is the single biggest skill you need to learn.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, what do you mean debug my program ? I am still new to programming and i am not familiar with all the terms you Qualified programmers use .

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, In this case i assigned fac with the ask in the array , will it help if i assign it to Num[1] instead of ask

Comment: @RiaanVanSandwyk Hi, take a look at [How to debug small programs](https://www.google.com/amp/s/ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/amp/)

Comment: If you want to see if a number from the array has some property, you need to operate on that number from the array. But yeah, your next task is to use the debugger. Delphi has an excellent debugger.

Comment: @ModusTollens ,Thank you for the information . will debug my program in the future times

Comment: Well, if you want to know something, do some research. Start with the program documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct for the procedure to return the position, judging by how you wrote the code. This is because `fac` stores the *position* of the array's element you work with (the array being `Num`). So, you're testing if the **position** you're working with divides 50, not the actual number.

```
 procedure TForm1.btnDisplayCriteriaClick(Sender: TObject);
 var
 i :integer;
 begin     
  if rbgCriteria.ItemIndex=0 then
   for I := 1 to ask do     
    if (num[i] mod 50) = 0 then
     redDisplay.Lines.Add(IntToStr(num[i])+' is a factor of 50')      
 end;
```

Comment: but to display is it still going to be num[fac]; or am i going to replace it with num[i]

Comment: Is `num[i]`. Sorry. Missed that one.

Comment: One thing I found is that Num[i] mod 50 = 0 won"t work but when i switched the arrands around like 50 mod numbers[i] = 0 it worked

Comment: If he had compilation errors, it was not because of my code from the answer.

Comment: It's not a compilation error, rather a logic error. He wants to know if Num[I] divides into 50 exactly. 1 2 5 10 25 and 50 are the possible candidates. Asker got it wrong in the code in the question.

Comment: I know. My comment was addressed to the user above me who deleted his comment in the mean time.